# How to validate a form with many input elements in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I am working on a form to post a leave form in a web page and I need to post the input in other page to process the input. I need to validate the empty fields and post the variables in a secure way. Here I have the code below ,this code just post the variables without any security and it has vulnerability. Please give a suitable code.

```
<?php include "header.php" ?>
<form action="process_leave.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="border-width:0px;">
<table cellpadding="10" rules="all" border="2" style="border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;width:100%;">
<tr >                                       
<FIELDSET  style="width: 1000px; height: 300px;">
<h4 align="left">TYPE OF LEAVE :</h4>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">ON DUTY<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">CASUAL LEAVE<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">MEDICAL LEAVE<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">LOSS OF PAY<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">ENCASHMENT LEAVE<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">VOCATIONAL LEAVE<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="OD">PERMISSION<br/>
</FIELDSET>
<FIELDSET>
<h4 align="left">DETAILS:</h4>
NO OF DAYS :<input type="text" name="no_of_days"><br><br>
FROM<input type="date" name="from">TO<input type="date" name="to"><br><br>
LEAVE AVAILED:<input type="text" name="avail_leave"><br><br>
REASON FOR LEAVE :<input type="text" name="reason"><br>
<br>
</FIELDSET>
<FIELDSET>
<h4 align="left">ALTERNATE ARRANGEMENTS :</h4>
DATE <input type="date" name="alternate"><br><br>
PERIOD<select name="period">
<option value="1" name="period">1</option>
<option value="2" name="period">2</option>
<option value="3" name="period">3</option>
<option value="4" name=" period">4</option>
<option value="5" name=" period">5</option>
<option value="6" name=" period">6</option>
<option value="7" name=" period">7</option>
<option value="8" name=" period">8</option>
</select><br><br>
SEM:<input type="text" name="semester"><br><br>
FACULTY NAME:<input type="text" name="fac_name"><br><br>
DESIGNATION:<input type="text" name="fac_desg"><br><br>
DEPARTMENT:<input type="text" name="dept"><br><br>
APPROVED BY :<input type="radio" name="group2" >HOD
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="pricipal">PRINCIPAL<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</FIELDSET>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="m_state"  value="Started" />
 &nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="m_res"  value="1366" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice. Make a form. Hire us for free to make it secure for you.

Comment: What "security vulnerability" are you referring to?  There's no PHP code posted here, so there's nothing for us to advise.  In general you want to: 1) Validate business logic for each field both client-side (good UX) and server-side (enforce business logic); and 2) Never implicitly trust user input and make sure it's property sanitized before using it in any other context, such as a database query (basically treat input as data, never as executable code).

Comment: i need the code for validation ,if the form is submitted with empty values  then the error should be raised representing  (it is empty)....

Answer (score 0):

You could use php's session_id class, for a more secure way of passing $_POST variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use several functionality like

- generate an encryption key using php and display it in form in a
  hidden field. while checking the form data, you should change that
  encryption key matches with the one which you generate.
- Use the captcha
- Use mysqli_real_escape_string() before inserting data to database.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be advised. Please mention use of mysqli_* or parameterized queries.

Comment: @ I Can Has Cheezburger. ok

Answer (score 0):

Input validation can be done both way: 
 1. Client Side
 2. Server Side

1.Client side validation demo:

[Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

[Source](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery-validation-1.11.1.zip)

2.Server side validation:
-Check for empty each Posted field
i.e. `if(isset($_POST['var_name']) && $_POST['var_name']!='')`{}

-Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` while passing it in mysql query for security purpose.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be advised. Please mention use of mysqli_* or parameterized queries.

Comment: thank u so much ..can u explain with an example with the above code for a single input element , so that i can implement completely for server side validation